# How to push notification to specific user Node + AngularJS + Laravel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, redis, laravel-5

I need help how to push notification to specific user. I can now push notifcation but all user will get that notification. I can filter it on clinet side but I think it is unsecure...

First I send data with laravel 5:

```
$redis = Redis::connection();
$redis->publish('update.answer', json_encode($events));
```

here is my node.js i emite data:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('update.group', function(err, count) {
});
redis.subscribe('update.question', function(err, count) {
});
redis.subscribe('update.answer', function(err, count) {
});
redis.subscribe('update.comment', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(message);
    io.emit(channel, message);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

and with angularjs I take data and push to the client.

```
socket.on('update.answer',function(data){
            if($scope.remove){
                $scope.remove = false;
            }
            $scope.feed = $("#feed").val();
            if(parseInt($scope.feed) === parseInt(data.userID)){
            $scope.answers.push(data);
            $scope.$digest();
            }
        });
```

WIth this part:

```
 $scope.feed = $("#feed").val();
                    if(parseInt($scope.feed) === parseInt(data.user_id) && data.admin_id !== null){

}
```

I check if client should get notification but it is unsecure...

Any way to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

To push message to specific user , you must store his/her reference somewhere.

for ex

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
     socket.on('add-user', function(data){
        clients[data.username] = socket;
      });
});
```

now to push message to specific user just use his username to retrive his socket

```
clients[data.username].emit(channel, message);
```

**Update : Explanation**

**This Assume that each user who uses you web app is having some sort of authentication.**

As soon as user login into your application , let him join on the nodejs backend socket.

**on client side**

```
socket.emit('add-user',userObj); 
        });
```

userObj is object that contains user details,you can send the username alone too

```
socket.emit('add-user',username);
```

in your nodejs first decalre one array that contains the socket of all the users who joins the website

```
var clients = [];
```

now in your nodejs application write this additional code

```
   io.on('connection', function(socket) {
         socket.on('add-user', function(data){
            clients[data.username] = socket;
          });
    });
```

up to this moment the user who login into your website will call `add-user` event from client side which will in turn call `add-user` on nodejs and there socket will be added into the clients array

now to send message to any particular user you must know there username,so if you know the username of the user then you can simply emit message to them using

```
clients[data.username].emit(channel, message);
```

Comment: Could you explain me on my example how to do that?

Comment: first question, how you determine which user to send the message..?

Comment: When push data, inside data I have `data.userID`  you see this part: `parseInt($scope.feed) === parseInt(data.user_id)` $scope.feed is hidden intput in html for user and if that equal with `data.user_id` then user should get notification in other case he should't get message.

Comment: that's awesome,that mean the message you pass in io.emit do contain userid

Comment: Yes, it contains userids. That users should get notifications... :)

Comment: this post will help you better and its quite simlilar to what you want to do https://github.com/roshansingh/realtime-notifications/blob/master/server/server.js